# Invalidate() doesn't call OnDraw() in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android

In my code I use onTouchEvent() to draw different image based on my touch down/up.

Below is my code sample.

When I do Invalidate() in touch_Down, it doesn't call onDraw() immediately, but rather, it calls after my touch_Up completes.
so I always see my touch_Up image after OnDraw().

Please, help.

```
private void MyView_Touch(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Down)
    {
        SetSelectedPart(Resource.Drawable.Green);
    }
    else if (e.Event.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
    {
        SetSelectedPart(Resource.Drawable.Blue);
    }
}

private void SetSelectedPart(int resourceId)
{
    myDrawable = Context.Resources.GetDrawable(resourceId, null);
    Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    myDrawable.Draw(canvas);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tested your code. The OnDraw method is called. I think the reason of the picture is not shown is that you are not using `SetBounds()` method.

For example:

```
protected override void OnDraw(Canvas canvas)
{
    if (myDrawable != null)
    {
        myDrawable.SetBounds(0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height);
        myDrawable.Draw(canvas);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Billy, 
Thanks for your reply. I have tried with setbounds and still doesn't work, i am always seeing blue icon, since the OnDraw() is called only after UP event.

Comment: @Praddy Could you provide your other code(.cs and .axml)?